# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Querying Between Times

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an orders table with `order_date` datetime column. Need a query that fetches records across all dates within a specific time range.

Example: fetch orders across all dates between 7am ET and 9am ET.

Something like:

```
Order.where('time(order_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', '7am', '9am')
```

start and end times are coming from text fields where user can enter 2am, 3pm, 6am etc string values

Comment: I don't want to search between dates instead I just want to query between times i.e records only between 7am and 9am every day

Comment: what's your database?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Answer (score 5):

## Method 1: `EXTRACT`

You can use `EXTRACT` to get the hour from `order_date`:

```
Order.where('EXTRACT(hour FROM order_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', 7, 20)
```

Note that I specified `20` (8 pm) as the upper range. If I used `21` then `order_date` with a time component of 21:30 would match which is not what we want.

You can wrap the query above in a scope:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between, -> (start_hour, end_hour) {
    where('EXTRACT(hour FROM order_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_hour, end_hour - 1)
  }
end
```

There are also some other concerns you may like to address, for example checking `start_hour` and `end_hour` for valid values (e.g an hour of -1 is invalid).

This method is simple but is limited to full hours (you can add minutes and seconds but the method would become convoluted).

## Method 2: Explicit cast to `time`

`Time` in Ruby stores both a date *and* time. For example:

```
Time.parse('15:30:45') # => 2017-01-02 15:30:45 +0100
```

You can pass `Time` to PostgreSQL and cast it to Postgres `time` type explicitly:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between, -> (start_time, end_time) {
    where('order_date::time BETWEEN ?::time AND ?::time', start_time, end_time)
  }
end
```

The advantage of this method is flexibility. The downside is a bit more complexity in handling the time in the UI. The scope expects a pair of `Time` objects. There are many ways to obtain them, for example: `Time.parse('12:17')`.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, this will search for orders between now and 1 month ago:

```
Order.where('order_date < ?', Time.now).where('order_date > ?', Time.now - 1.month)
```

Use `Time#parse` if you need to convert a string like `"9am"` into an object.

```
irb(main):006:0> Time.parse('9 AM')
=> 2016-12-27 09:00:00 -0700
```

The final code would probably look something like this:

```
morning = Time.parse('9 AM')
# 2016-12-27 09:00:00 -0700

night = Time.parse('10 PM')
# 2016-12-27 22:00:00 -0700

Order.where('order_date > ?', morning).where('order_date < ?', night)


Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders ` WHERE (order_date > '2016-12-27 16:00:00.000000') AND (order_date < '2016-12-28 05:00:00.000000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Order.where(order_date: Time.parse("7am")..Time.parse("9am"))
```

Comment: This seems to be incorrect as `Time` in Ruby is a date _and_ time. I tested it's incorrect locally. The generated query is `SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE ("teachers"."created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)` and `[["created_at", 2017-01-03 06:00:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2017-01-03 08:00:00 UTC]]` are substituted. Your query selects orders places _today_ between 7 am and 9 am. @Arif needs orders places on _any_ day.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySql `HOUR` function:

```
Order.where("HOUR(order_date) between 7 and 9")
```

Pay attention to the Time Zone you are using while querying!